# repeat inside dynamic popover - angularjs and ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, popover, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to show the user a list of items inside of a popover that is all inside an ng-repeat.  I'm using angularjs as well as the ui-bootstrap package (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat='session in sessions'>
     <p popover="{{session.items}}">view items</p>
</div>
```

This will show the array session.items for each session, which contains the information I want to show. However, this shows the brackets of the array as well.

Does anyone know a clean way to do this?

any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From ui-bootstrap site you can read

```
 uib-popover - Takes text only and will escape any HTML provided for   the popover body.
```

So if you provide `session.items` you will get string '[my array content]'. In my opinion you need to use `uib-popover-template` where your template would be like

```
 <div ng-repeat='session in sessions'>
   <p uib-popover-template="'urlToMyTemplateHere'">view items</p>
 </div>

 ------ Template
 <div ng-repeat="item in session.items" ng-bind="item"></div>
```

`uib-popover-template` takes an url to the template so you have to create file for it to be fetched or try this approach ( I don't really like it but just for testing )

```
 <div ng-repeat='session in sessions'>
   <p uib-popover-template="'iamabadapproachtemplate.html'">view items</p>
 </div>

 <script type="text/ng-template" id="iamabadapproachtemplate.html">
    <div ng-repeat="item in session.items" ng-bind="item"></div>
 </script>
```